# Want to pass varialble in string variable in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, variables

I want to pass variable in string so that later in script value is assigned to it.

```
$message="hi $(name) your salary $(salary) is credited in your XYZ account";
foreach($arrmsgvar as $key => $value){  
    $temp=array_search($value[1],$upfileformat);        
    if($temp){
       $replacement='$row['.$temp.']';
       $message=str_replace($value[0],$replacement,$message);   
    }
 }
```

**I am getting string "hi $row[1] your salary $row[2] is credited in your XYZ account" in
 $message**

```
$xdata="";
foreach($Spreadsheet as $key => $row){  
   $xdata.= "`$memid`|`$source`|`$mobile`|`$message`|`0`|`$msgid`||";
}
echo $xdata;
```

**and getting `1`|`2`|`12345678`|`hi $row[1] your salary $row[2] is credited in your XYZ account`|`0`|`4`||**  **,in $xdata**

how can i get that value of $row array in $xdata final output? would anyone tell me 
   a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

```
$messages = array();
$message  = "hi %s your salary %d is credited in your %s account";
foreach ($arrmsgvar as $key => $value){  
  $temp = array_search($key, $upfileformat);
  if ($temp !== false) {
    $messages[$key] = sprintf($message, $name, $salary, $account);
  }
}
var_dump($messages);
```

I'm not entirly sure where a number of variables are comming from nevertheless the
above code will give you an idea on how to implement `sprintf`, the values
`$name`,`$salary`,`$account` can be replaced with whatever the text values should be.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: actually i didn’t have values of $name, $salary, $account at the time of assignment, if you look at my code $replacement='$row['.$temp.']'; .. i am try to pass just variable into string and later value is assigned to variable in   foreach($Spreadsheet as $key => $row){ } in this loop

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using your own string replace, look at using [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php).